How do I hide the details pane in CapCut?
In the desktop version of the video editing program CapCut, how do I hide the "Details" pane in the top right? I would like to make more room for the video player section.


You can just drag the top of the "Details" pane and it will move above the other panes. Then you'll see three buttons, Restore (to bring it back), Fullscreen, and Minimize.
You can see what I mean from provided image below:


